# PHP/MySQL code to process associated entries

Tags: php, mysql

I have table:

```
Name     GroupID    etc...
ABC
ABC
DEF
DEF
DEF
KKK
LLL
III
III
```

I'd like a PHP/MYSQL mix to process into this:

```
Name     GroupID    etc...
ABC       1
ABC       1
DEF       2 
DEF       2
DEF       2
KKK       0
LLL       0
III       3 
III       3
```

ie. If entries with duplicated Name exist for the row (exactly string match), it will assign a GroupID (increment automatically) to all of the entries with that Name. If the entry is unique name, it will assign a 0 to the GroupID

My table has 250,000 entries, what is the fastest way to achieve this? Working code would be nice but high level algorithm is good enough to get me going.

Thanks!

Comment: my php method would be to loop through the names in order, keep track of the previous name, when the current and previous don't match increment the Groupid. update each row as you go. there amy be a super smart mysql way however. -- oh look there it is now :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done with a quick PHP script, but I like the idea of letting the database handle it by itself.

You could probably do this with a clever `UPDATE` join, but because I can't test it I'll use a temporary table instead. The idea is to select all values for `Name` having counts > 1 and assign a row number to them into a temporary table.  Then use an update join to modify the GroupID in the original table.

```
SET @rownum=0;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE groupnums (groupid INT, Name VARCHAR(16), numgroups INT)
  SELECT
    @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS groupid, 
    Name,  
    COUNT(*) AS numgroups 
  FROM original_table 
  GROUP BY Name
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

UPDATE 
  original_table
  JOIN groupnums ON original_table.Name = groupnums.Name
SET original_table.GroupID = groupnums.groupid
```

Then set the remaining ones to 0

```
UPDATE original_table SET GroupID='0' WHERE GroupID IS NULL
```

And get rid of the temporary table.

```
DROP TABLE groupnums;
```

#### Update:

After testing this quickly for myself, I find that although it works you won't get directly incremental values for `groupid`. The `@rownum` is incremented for each row rather than each group so you'll end up with groups like the following with gaps in between.

```
/* Sample results - groups work, but have gaps between GroupID */
Name     GroupID    etc...
ABC       1
ABC       1
DEF       3
DEF       3
DEF       3
KKK       0
LLL       0
III       6 
III       6
```

### Update 2 I overcomplicated this a bit.

On deeper thought, the `@rownum` isn't needed at all. Just use an auto-increment id in the temporary table. This should produce incremental `GroupID` without the gaps in between. Use the same `UPDATE` statement to join against this as above.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE groupnums (groupid INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, Name VARCHAR(16), numgroups INT)
  SELECT 
    NULL AS groupid
    Name,
    COUNT(*) AS numgroups
  FROM original_table
  GROUP BY Name
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```